# Simple JS vanilla/react function rewrite, but how?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I have a written a nasty bit of code over and over,
but how can I make it a reusable function (and how would I call it?)
step: step - 'x' <--- this is the only functional bit that actual changes!

This is the nasty code :(

```
  prevStep2 = () => {
    const { step } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      step: step - 6
    });
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  };
  //Back to step 3
  prevStep3 = () => {
    const { step } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      step: step - 5
    });
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  };
  //Back to step 4
  prevStep4 = () => {
    const { step } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      step: step - 4
    });
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  };
  //Back to step 5
  prevStep5 = () => {
    const { step } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      step: step - 3
    });
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  };
  //Back to step 6
  prevStep6 = () => {
    const { step } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      step: step - 2
    });
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  };
  //Back to step 7
  prevStep7 = () => {
    const { step } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      step: step - 1
    });
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  };
```

My attempt at the rewrite:

```
function backToStep(stepNumber){
    const { step } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      step: step - stepNumber
    });
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

Called like

```
<button onClick={this.backToStep(5)}>Test</button>
```

But not sure if it would work properly!

Answer (score 0):

`onClick` expects a function. `this.backToStep(5)` returns `void`, so you have a problem. You need either to pass an anonymous function to `onClick`:

```js
<button onClick={() => this.backToStep(5)}>Test</button>
```

Or to make `backToStep` return a function:

```js
function backToStep(stepNumber) {
  return () => {
    const { step } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      step: step - stepNumber
    });
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
}

<button onClick={this.backToStep(5)}>Test</button>
```

Also, it's considered [a good practice](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) to use the callback parameter when your `setState` depends on the actual state.

> If the next state depends on the current state, we recommend using the updater function form, instead:

```js
this.setState(prevState => ({
  step: prevState.step - stepNumber
}))
```